# block visitors with read only access to reach site contents via "settings" Icon

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-permissions, site-contents, access-rights

I am giving access to guest users to my SharePoint online communication site, but I see that they can reach (even on read only permission level) the site contents via settings button on the top of the screen.

I tried to create a permission level after creating a custom permission level with th "View Application Pages" unchecked as suggested, but then the user can't get access to the site  at all.

would appreciate help, thanks!

Comment: Don't think this is possible, is there a particular reason you want to hide it? All the site contents page does is show a user what they have access to in the site?

Comment: Basically, I don't want them to roam around "behind the scenes". 
It's a nice to have, but I would like it better that way :)

Comment: The site contents page is only a listing of the lists and libraries that they have access to anyway. It can actually be very useful for end users.

Comment: Not really. this has some additional information, which I don't want them to mess with or misunderstand.

Comment: Yes, but this information is only information that they have access to regardless. It's accessible via other APIs/endpoints.

Comment: in one way or another.
and not all directly. some of it is used in processes, and not directly in their reach.
I prefer to control what they have access to or not, and in what manners.
but I understand that there is no way to do it (At least, not OOTB ).
so thank you! :)